# `com.sun.org.slf4j.internal.Logger` in JDK and wrong usage

Tags: java, logging, xml-signature

When dealing with XMLSignature generation and verification I had to debug and came across strange logging behavior (I would call it bugs, but maybe I don't have the full picture).

The logger access method `com.sun.org.slf4j.internal.LoggerFactory#getLogger` is part of the jdk and is used internally to obtain a logger instance - checked with jdk12.

That logger is used for example by `org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMReference` and other different XMLSignature related classes.

The returned logger is an instance of `com.sun.org.slf4j.internal.Logger` and that is a simple 
wrapper that delegates every call to an instance of `java.util.logging.Logger`.

**My first observation**

The placeholder `{}` known from slf4j is used in log massage and I think, the author expected some sort of parameter replacement should be done.

Example from `org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMReference`

```
LOG.debug("Reference object uri = {}", uri);
```

Since the logger is a simple wrapper and doesn't do any processing, this isn't replaced.

My log message is the unreplaced log string.

**Update**
The logger doesn't do anything at all:

```
    public void debug(String s, Throwable e) {
        impl.log(java.util.logging.Level.FINE, s, e);
    }

    public void debug(String s, Object... o) {
        impl.log(java.util.logging.Level.FINE, s, o);
    }
```

Question: Is this a bug or did I forget to turn on "something"?

**My second observation**

In `com.sun.org.slf4j.internal.Logger` debug log level is mapped to fine and trace log level is mapped to fine as well. I would have expected that trace level is mapped to finest, 
but that doesn't matter, because trace isn't used anyway.

**My last observation**

Why did they use slf4j in the package name? This is very confusing.

Comment: SLF4J is not just a simple wrapper. The `debug(String, Object)` method is supposed to substitute the first `{}` with the string value of the object, before forwarding to the underlying logger implementation. --- Are you saying your log file has the exact text `Reference object uri = {}` and that the `uri` parameter was ignored?

Comment: @Andreas: Updated answer. I don't see where this replacement happens and if it's just the first parameter that is replaced, the log messages `LOG.debug("Reference [{}] is valid: {}", ref.getURI(), refValid);` in `org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMXMLSignature` won't work, would it?

Comment: `java.uitl.logging.Logger` use `java.util.logging.Formatter` to format the messages, which use `java.text.MessageFormat` for formatting. So the log message should be "Reference object uri = {0}".

Comment: @Peter The `debug()` method has overloads for multiple arguments too, e.g. [`debug​(String format, Object... arguments)`](http://www.slf4j.org/apidocs/org/slf4j/Logger.html#debug(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object...)). --- As for the `{}` substitution, that is something SLF4J defines and implements, not the underlying logging implementation. See the [SLF4J FAQ](http://www.slf4j.org/faq.html#logging_performance) for more detail.

Comment: Of course, that's the real SLF4J, but it appears that `com.sun.org.slf4j.internal.Logger` is not a rebranded SLF4J, but a fake thin wrapper, *misleading* the programmer who wrote that code into using SLF4J substitution instead of JUL substitution (as [mentioned by samabcde](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61098092/com-sun-org-slf4j-internal-logger-in-jdk-and-wrong-usage?noredirect=1#comment108098094_61098092)), so your original thought is correct: **It is a bug**.

Comment: I'm having huge problems with com.sun.org.slf4j conflicting with org.slf4j IntelliJ seems determined to use this faulty library instead of the real one, and I have no idea how to fix it.